# Am I supposed to save the salt somewhere when hashing a password?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, hash

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sergio");
        Console.WriteLine(HashString("Sergio"));
        Console.WriteLine(HashString("Sergio"));
        Console.WriteLine(HashString("Sergio"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string HashString(string value)
    {
        int minSaltSize = 4;
        int maxSaltSize = 8;
        Random random = new Random();
        int saltSize = random.Next(minSaltSize, maxSaltSize);
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

        //Convert the string value into a byte array.
        UTF8Encoding utf8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] plainTextBytes = utf8Encoder.GetBytes(value);

        //Allocate an array to hold the text bytes and the salt bytes.
        byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new Byte[saltBytes.Length + plainTextBytes.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < plainTextBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainTextBytes[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainTextBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];
        }

        HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);
        string hashedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        return hashedValue;
    }
}
```

The result of my code is that hashed "Sergio" is different everytime. This is caused by the random factor included in the salt. My question is, am I supposed to save the salt somewhere? Or do I define a constant salt in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I would say you need to know it so either you save it or you rely on a fixed value stored somewhere.

Comment: You shouldn't write such code yourself. Even experts screw this up. Use a proven, off-the-shelf authentication provider. Reinventing the wheel is usually not a good thing in software, but it crypto it can be deadly. Don't let your app become the next Gawker!

Comment: @Craig: Hahaha, true true. But I always like to learn how things work, even at a superficial level. Upvote either way.

Comment: @Craig: By the way, you mentioned off the shelf solutions. Which one would you recommend I use?

Comment: @Sergio, yes, it's fine to do this just for learning. For web apps I use the built-in ASP.NET providers. For Windows apps I use domain authentication, mostly. Depends on the type of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been a fan of GUIDs for the salt and SHA512 for the hash. CPU time isn't an issue since it's only during authentication.

but yes, you need to store the hash so you can append it to the incoming password.

storedpassword = hash(salt+password)

if you forget the salt, you can't compare the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different salts then you will want to store both the hashed password and the salt in the db.  You can also chose to store the salt in an app.config / web.config file if it is the same salt.

Comment: Using the same salt is not great.  That basically partially defeats the purpose of the salt (as it would enable a user to iterate over a dictionary once for all passwords rather than once per password).  If you want to use an application specific salt, that's good.  But also use per user salts (`hash(password + userSalt + appSalt)`)...

Answer (score 1):

You should save the salt someplace because you need to use the same salt when computing the hash again. However, you don't want to use a constant because that reduces the effectiveness of the salt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to create the salt/hash and combine the two values together:

```
public sealed class PasswordHash
{
    const int SaltSize = 16, HashSize = 20, HashIter = 10000;
    readonly byte[] _salt, _hash;
    public PasswordHash(string password)
    {
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(_salt = new byte[SaltSize]);
        _hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
    }
    public PasswordHash(byte[] hashBytes)
    {
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, SaltSize, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
    }
    public PasswordHash(byte[] salt, byte[] hash)
    {
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, _salt = new byte[SaltSize], 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(hash, 0, _hash = new byte[HashSize], 0, HashSize);
    }
    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = new byte[SaltSize + HashSize];
        Array.Copy(_salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(_hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, HashSize);
        return hashBytes;
    }
    public byte[] Salt { get { return (byte[])_salt.Clone(); } }
    public byte[] Hash { get { return (byte[])_hash.Clone(); } }
    public bool Verify(string password)
    {
        byte[] test = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, HashIter).GetBytes(HashSize);
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; HashSize; i++)
            if (test[i] != _hash[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

http://csharptest.net/?p=470

Answer (score 0):

Absolutly. Use always a new salt per hashed password and not a constant. Having the same salt for all passwords would be unsafe ([defense against rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)).

Save it somewhere, e.g. in a database in an extra field or even in the same field with the hashed password together ([bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for example does it similar like that) if you can't add an extra field to your database logic.

But always use a new random salt per password.